# How to detect only specific objects like cardboard boxes?

Tags: python, opencv

Imagine a factory warehouse, there are different sized boxes which loaded with products. I want to measure these.boxes with a camera. There is no background, background is natural factory warehouse. I have a code for measuring. But this code measuring everything. I want to measure only boxes.

I have code for measuring objects but How to detect only cardboard boxes with opencv?

Should i detect with color filter or with yolo?

Also maybe user will measure other objects instead of cardboard boxes like industrial machines etc. Maybe i need more general solution...

camera facing with width,height(180degrees).

[image]

As you see code measuring everything but I want only cardboard Boxes. I have tried filter colors with Hue, Saturation, Volume. But it didnt work because I'm using Aruco perimeter. Aruco perimeter is Black and White. When i lost other colors, Aruco perimeter is lost too. And maybe there would be different colored boxes.

Comment: @toyotaSupra  Can you help?

Comment: I don't used Aruco. You don't needed yolo and detect color

Comment: Btw, I couldn't find on disks.

Comment: thanks anyway. İf dont need use yolo, What should i do?

Answer (score 2):

You can try detecting rectangular or quadrilateral contours in a copy of B/W frame and then correlate the contours to the original(colored) frame. Thus you can apply color filtering on it to detect cardboard box. The advantage of this over DL would be DL might take more processing power.

Comment: Thanks for help, do you know any example about this? or can you share methods for this?

Comment: This might help you, its plynomial detection using number of sides of an object. https://dev.to/simarpreetsingh019/detecting-geometrical-shapes-in-an-image-using-opencv-4g72

Comment: what if is there different colored cardboard boxes instead of brown? Also how to still remain Black and White aruco perimeter? by the way nice solution.

Comment: Just create a list of all the color RGB values of boxes you have and check the color of the contour object. If the color of object is in your color list, its a box.
As for aruco perimeter, you can use a black and white frame of image. You can have multiple copies of the same frame, one can be a monochrome (B/W) for permimeter calculation, other can be a colored frame for object detection.

Answer (score 1):

Did your use any deep learning(DL) methods for cardboardboxes detection? If not, I recommend you to use yolov5 method based DL or choose some machine learning methods such as HOG with SVM. The advantage you use DL methods is that you only need label this boxes and pass the data(images and annotations) to model without worrying about whatever other object.

Comment: Have you got any example for choosing specific object and measuring it?

Answer (score 0):

I tagged the cells using Labelme software (you can tag any object with it), and then I trained yolact's model with the images and annotations. Figure 1 shows the results that the model predicted a new image.
[image: The result of identifying cells]

Comment: When i tagged box and detect it, how to delete rest of picture? Or how to measure only boxes?